# How to check if an array contains a Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have this code below where I generate a fibonacci sequence that stops based on the highest number in NSArray numbers. I am trying to check if the numbers in the numbers array are all fibonacci numbers. How do I compare the numbers and fibonacciArray so that my function will return yes if the numbers are all fibonacci numbers or no if some of the numbers in numbers array are not fibonacci numbers?

EDIT: Here are the example test arrays if that helps..

```
 [self onlyFibonacciValues:@[@21, @2, @8, @3]];
 [self onlyFibonacciValues:@[@21, @6, @2]];


- (BOOL)onlyFibonacciValues:(NSArray *)numbers {

NSArray *newNumbers = [numbers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue" ascending:YES]]];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [newNumbers mutableCopy];

NSInteger firstFibonacci = 1;
NSInteger secondFibonacci = 2;

NSInteger lastObjectInArray = [sortedArray.lastObject integerValue];

NSMutableArray *fibonacciArray = [NSMutableArray new];
[fibonacciArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:firstFibonacci]];
[fibonacciArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:secondFibonacci]];

while (lastObjectInArray > secondFibonacci) {

    secondFibonacci = secondFibonacci + firstFibonacci;
    firstFibonacci = secondFibonacci - firstFibonacci;

    [fibonacciArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:secondFibonacci]];

}

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to generate an all new array of Fibonacci numbers in order to check the values from the current array. All you need to do is to walk through elements of the current array, checking each element to the next Fibonacci number. You can do it in a single loop:

```
int curr = 1, prev = 1;
for (NSNumber *n in newNumbers) { // You do not need a mutable copy of the sorted array
    int v = [n intValue];
    while (curr < v) {
        curr += prev;
        prev = curr-prev;
    }
    // At this point curr is the next Fibonacci number
    // which is greater than or equal to the current value
    // in the array. Holes and duplicates are allowed.
    if (curr != v) return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Comment: Would your formula work though if numbers was this?
      [self onlyFibonacciValues:@[@21, @6, @2]];

Comment: @JonJungemann You mean you are allowed to have a "hole" in the sequence?.. Not currently, but the change is rather small...

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have been more specific

Comment: @JonJungemann That's OK - all I needed to add was a simple loop.

Comment: How does that work if there can be a skip in the number sequence? The function can only return no if there is a number in numbers array that is not a fibonacci number.

Comment: @JonJungemann The function returns `YES` if it does not find a non-Fibonacci number in the array, i.e. when all numbers are from the Fibonacci sequence. Since you array is sorted, the inner loop that makes the next Fibonacci number can pick up where it left off on the previous iteration. The nested `while` loop skips numbers to deal with "holes" in the sequence.

Comment: I added the two different tests of numbers at the top

Comment: @JonJungemann I saw that. The first one produces a `YES` on my computer; the second one produces a `NO`.